# Changing pandas dataframe based on linear reggression R^2 values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I need to fit a linear equation to a pandas dataframe and depending on the fit of the line (R^2 value) I need to remove rows of the dataframe.  I am using SciPy linregress function. I have tried a few ways but have yet to find a way that works how I need it to which is something like:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress([df['p_rel',df['y_BET'])
r_sq = r_value ** 2

if r_sq < 0.995:
    '''remove last row from dataframe and run linregress again. repeat this until r_sq >= 0.995 '''
```

Comment: Could you post few lines of df?

Comment: I would but dont know how to post a dataframe considering it based of a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put it into a function?

```
def regress(df):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['p_rel'], df['y_BET'])

    if r_value ** 2 < 0.995:
        regress(df.iloc[:-1, :])  # call again and regress with last row removed
    else:
        DO STUFF WITH RESULT
```

This recursion is guaranteed to end: we are regressing two columns (so two `n x 1` structures), and recursively updating this to `n-1, n-2, ..., 2`. It stops at the latest at `2`, as a regression over two `2 x 1` structures is guaranteed to have R-squared equal to one (and thus evaluate to false in the if statement).

**Edit:** if you want to use the result outside the function (see comment), this works:

```
def regress(df):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['p_rel'], df['y_BET'])

    if r_value ** 2 < 0.995:
        return regress(df.iloc[:-1, :])  # call again and regress with last row removed
    else:
        return slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err 

# call like so:
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = regress(df)

# use the results here
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried a function but I want to be able to call slope and intercept outside the function but had no luck.

Comment: Doing this makes the R^2 = 1 which isnt what I need.   I would like the function to stop when R^2 >= 1.

Comment: @Fungie, it does. Have you considered that maybe for `n > 2`, the R-squared doesn't reach the threshold? I don't know your data, but your desired R-squared is very strict, so it could well be that there is simply nothing matching until `n = 2`, at which your R-squared is guaranteed to equal 1.

Comment: For this dataset if I delete the first 3 rows the fit is greater than 0.995, I have tested this but I want this to be a general expression so I can apply it to other datasets.

Comment: @Fungie, you say you delete the first rows? Yet in your coding example, you mention deleting the last rows. I assumed you wanted to delete the last rows (as per your example), so I coded for that. If you however wish to delete the first rows, simply change `df.iloc[:-1, :]` to `df.iloc[1:, :]`.

Comment: Yeah I just got confused. I got it working properly now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [generator
expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to create an iterator
which can iterate over the sequence of `linregress` calls. Since it is an
one-pass iterator, the calls to `linregress` will be delayed until necessary.

Then you could use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to iterate over the generator expression, dropping results until the `R**2` value is greater than 0.995:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import itertools as IT
regressions = (stats.linregress([df['p_rel'].iloc[:-i], df['y_BET'].iloc[:-i]) 
                                for i in range(len(df)))
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = next(IT.dropwhile(
    lambda x: x[2]**2 < 0.995, regressions))
```

You could also wrap this in a function:

```
def regress_dropping_tail_outliers(x, y, threshold=0.995):
    regressions = (stats.linregress([x.iloc[:-i], y.iloc[:-i]) for i in range(len(x)))
    return next(IT.dropwhile(lambda x: x[2]**2 < threshold, regressions))

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = regress_dropping_tail_outliers(
    df['p_rel'], df['y_BET'])
```